# "sudo apt upgrade" for 2 ubuntu distributions at once

Tags: dual-boot, apt, upgrade, downloads

I run 2 ubuntu distributions (both vanilla) with dual boot on a single machine, since I use one for regular purposes and one specifically for building. There are many common apps that run in both distributions. When an update is available for any of these common apps, is there a way to upgrade the apps on both the distributions while downloading only once?

Comment: Sure. You can copy the cache directory over from 1 to the other machine. But "There are many common apps " makes it problematic cuz you might copy something over that is not on the 2nd machine. You should do that when the systems are identical.

Comment: On first machine you will find the deb packages in `/var/cache/apt/archives`, you can copy them with `apt-move` (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptMoveHowto) - OR, better but need another machine, there is `apt-cacher`